# self join table

Tags: php, sql, t-sql

i have a table,

```
    new_id----old_id----created_on
    1234------5678------20100912
    5678------3456------20100808
```

etc.

i wrote this query,

```
$q = "select event1.new_id, event1.old_id, event1.created_on,event2.new_id, event2.old_id, event2.created_on
  FROM replaced_isbns event1
  JOIN replaced_isbns event2 
  ON event2.new_id = event1.old_id
  WHERE event1.new_id='$id'";
```

but i get result as 
5678 - 1234, ie only one row, i want all rows...

@webdestroya,

it gives only one row....
i want output like this,
For new_id 1234, old_id's are 5678,3456 etc

Comment: In your example, your table contains only 2 rows. Is this true for you actual data as well?

Answer (score 0):

if you want all rows than try `left outer join` and replace null with new id for example

```
SELECT
    event1.new_id, event1.old_id, event1.created_on,
    IFNULL(event2.new_id, event1.new_id),
    IFNULL(event2.old_id, event1.old_id),
    event2.created_on
FROM replaced_isbns event1
LEFT OUTER JOIN replaced_isbns event2 
  ON event2.new_id = event1.old_id
WHERE event1.new_id='$id'
```

check this may help you

Comment: @ pranay,
it returns no results

I want result like this,
For new_id 1234, old_id's are 5678,3456 etc

Comment: Hi,
it give me only 1234 - 5678

but i want, second result also ie    5678 - 3456

it should return all rows

Comment: problem is you are putting id in your where condition if you want all record remove where clause than u will get all data

Comment: by all rows i mean, rows matching the where clause. i get new_id from user, by that i have to select other rows. please help me. thanks.

Comment: does ORDER BY clause work with joins?

I tried to order by event1.created_on in above select query, but i dont see difference....

Comment: if it works than accept than answer and increase your acceptance percentange

Answer (score 0):

Why make a self join?

```
SELECT replaced_isbns.*
FROM replaced_isbns
WHERE new_id = '$id'
OR old_id = '$id'
```

Now, for each row in your result check if new_id = $id, or if old_id = $id.

Comment: it gives me only, 1234 - 5678, but i want result as,

for new_id 1234, old_id's are 5678,3456 etc....
it should return all rows....as in table.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood, you need all the old_ids for the new_id:-
for new_id:- 1234 old id' are 5678 and 3456.
similarly for second record:- for new_id:- 5678 old id' are 3456.
I have tested this and it is working fine.

```
select new_id,b.old_id from 
   (select old_id from temp)
     as b inner join temp as a 
       on a.new_id!=b.old_id
```

Do let me know if this is the one you wanted or not.
I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to get the result you want using a query since there's no way to query recursive relations in SQL (well, ok, Oracle has START WITH ... CONNECT BY ... syntax and CTE, but I guess you're not using Oracle :p).

But on the other hand you could try to convert this adjacency list into a nested set, because getting a branch (all child records of a given parent) is very easy with nested sets. [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) is an interesting article on that subject.